# wine is installed but it's not running any windows application

Tags: kubuntu, windows, wine, winetricks

Everything with wine was working fine with wine until yesterday when i upgradede my php version from 7.4 to 8.0.

Since then i haven't been able to run any windows application.

if I check my wine version, it's still installed but not just working.

here is the error I get when I try to launch an application

```
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
001c:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
wine: Call from 0x7bc7c9e1 to unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.RtlPcToFileHeader, aborting
wine: Unimplemented function ntoskrnl.exe.RtlPcToFileHeader called at address 000000007BC7C9E1 (thread 0016), starting debugger...
000f:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to read pipe r = 0  count = 0!
003b:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\NDIS": 00000001
```

Comment: Have you tried what is says (`apt-get install wine32`)?

Comment: yes it pumps out a lot and lots of dependencies that the installation depends on.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details which provide clues as to your software stack you're using, also providing the specific command (and source) of your PHP packages may also provide clues, given you indicate it was the likely cause of your issue, would also help us to help you.